# Screenshot for Failures in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am having an issue that while running my automated script in **headless mode** and then getting screenshots for failure in an unknown language.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I doubt that this is the right place for this kind of question, nor that this question can be answered as such, because it lacks crucial information such as environment, errors, etc.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages and the actual and expected outputs.